# Check a collection if it contains all the values that match a certain value

Tags: java, collections

I want to know what the best way to know if all values of a collection match a particular value.

```
List<Integer> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

All I want to know is if all the entries in the "listOfStrings" match a particular value; for instance there is no integer that is not '1'.

I need the fastest solution to this. I have a solution with me but it is very rudimentary.

Comment: Why you you have a variable called listofStrings which is really of list of Integers?

Comment: I would start by renaming `listOfStrings` to `integers`. Good naming is one of the most important things in programming, and naming a list of integers "listOfStrings" is a really really bad idea.

Comment: What is your 'rudimentary' method? And when you say 'fastest' do you mean in terms of efficiency or what?

Comment: You should examine how your data structure is being built. If you can utilize a Set, you should; then checks like this are instant.

Comment: Thanks dcp and JB Nizet. I was actually working with a list of strings and for the sake of having it asked I named it listOfStrings.

Answer (score 4):

Loop through it:

```
public boolean checkAll(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfStrings.size(); i++) {
        String candidate = listOfStrings.get(i);
        if(candidate == null || !candidate.equals("1")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will fail if any value of the list is null... throw new NullPointerException().

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can use the [`allMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method of a stream to achieve this.

```
public boolean allOnes(Collection<Integer> values) {
    return values.parallelStream().allMatch(i -> i == 1);
}
```

Using a `parallelStream` will potentially yield better performance if there are multiple processors available.

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over your list with a simple `for` loop, and compare every value with your certain value (say 1). If one value from your list is not equal to the certain value, just set a boolean to false.

Comment: Just an additional note: If a value is not equal to the desired value, you should both set the boolean to false and break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
public boolean isFilled(String value, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        String toTest = list.get(i);
        if(toTest == null || !toTest.equals(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: -1. Doesn't even compile. You're comparing an int with a STring.

Comment: you know JB some people take the time out of their day to post from mobile devices (iphones) ect where they cant compile and fully check syntax errors. and later make revisions

Comment: Err, yes, so what? I take much time every day to post without compiling, and I find it normal to get a downvote if my answer is plain wrong. I'll happily remove my down vote if the answer is fixed. You don't need a compiler to know that you can't compare a STring with an int. And if you need one, why answer without a compiler at hand?

Comment: true i guess your helping enforce the quality of posts on here. There is a difference between a missing semi colon and comparing objects to primitive data types. Never really thought about it like that.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it. I didn't get a chance to compile it, I was on my phone. The concept is still the same though.

Comment: It's still wrong. You're comparing Strings with `!=`. `equals()` must be used to compare objects.

Comment: You're close to the solution. You missed a `!`: `if (!list.get(i).equals(value))`

Comment: In this case, using == instead of .equals should work anyways. I'll compile it when I get home

Comment: No, using `==` is not acceptable. Test with `Arrays.asList("ab")` for the list and `new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").toString()` for the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean x=true;
     ArrayList<Integer> listOfInts = new ArrayList<Integer>   (Arrays.asList(5,3,1,2,9,5,0,7));
    Integer target = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfInts.size(); i++)
    {
        if (listOfInts.get(i).equals(target)) // nothing
        {

        } else {
            x = false;
            break;// exits loop right after this
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: good catch, fixed though im not sure about the break statement to exit the loop. I dont think this is the smartest way to do it

Comment: It's OK, but the best way is to extract the loop to a method, and return from the method. You could also add `&& !x` to the stop condition of the loop. And it would be clearer with `if (!listOfInts.get(i).equals(target)) {x = false;}`: it doesn't need an empty if block followed by an else.

Comment: thanks, i wasnt sure if the ! worked in the front so i just made it the way i knew .equals would work

Answer (score -1):

To my astonishment, all the solutions proposed so far are just plain wrong, or contain a subtle bug, or could be more efficient.

Here's a solution that works fast whatever the kind of list is, and even if the list contains null elements:

```
public boolean listIsFilledWith(List<Integer> integers, int i) {
    Integer value = i; // transform the int into an Integer only once
    for (Integer element : integers) { // iterate using an iterator, to avoid performance problems with linked lists
        if (!value.equals(element)) { // value is not null, but element can be. Don't compare objects with == or !=
            return false; // return early
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the `.contains()` method that tells you whether the value exists in the list : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

```
myList.contains(1);
```

Note: it uses the `.equals()` method of the contained object (it might be useful in your future developments).

HIH
M.

Comment: This is not actually answering his (poorly phrased) question.

Comment: what do you understand then? (it is still better than looping with a for loop...)

Comment: That will tell him if some value is in the list, but not if all values in the list are that.

Comment: @ZNK-M Your way just checks to see if the list contains the value.  The OP wants to know how to check if EVERY element in the list is equal to the value.

Comment: sorry, I skipped that. But in fact, I don't see the point of having a list that contains dozen of 1... anyway...

Comment: Really? Suppose you have a bunch of features in a program, and you want to turn some on and some off. You need a compact way of knowing which are on and which are off (or in one of several states). That is a list of integers. Now suppose you need to know if any switch is off?

Comment: I would have used a map to link the feature and the status of it. but anyway I am not sure he knows what he is doing and this none of my business.